# Array of anonymous sub-structures in C

Tags: c

I would like to compose a structure that possesses a contiguous array of  flexible members that are, in turn, aggregation of few data fields. With that code pattern I want to: a) store multiple relevant data fields, b) have an array of such instances and c) destroy them all as simply as *free()*. The code bellow seems do the job:

```
struct s_symm_root{
       unsigned int size_c;
       struct {
         unsigned int symm_color;
         t_symm_gnrtr symm_gnrtr;
         } _[];
       } *symm_root;
unsigned int SIZE_C = 10;


symm_root = (struct s_symm_root*)malloc( sizeof(struct s_symm_root) + sizeof(*((struct s_symm_root*)NULL)->_) * SIZE_C );

symm_root->size_c = 1;
symm_root->_[0].symm_color = 2;
printf(" %d, %d, %ul.\n", symm_root->size_c, symm_root->_[0].symm_color, sizeof(*((struct s_symm_root*)NULL)->_));

free(symm_root);
```

My questions is if I can improve it a bit, specially,  get rid of that ugly *'_'* somehow? I thought about anonymous structures but IDK how to implement them...

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: [dont cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: You need to give the array a name, otherwise you can't index it.

Comment: But that's not how C works. You can have anonymous structs, but not anonymous arrays.

Comment: @Barmar In principle, it could be an extra bracket after the member to address the anonymous structure in array.

Comment: You mean something like `symm_root->symm_color[0]`? That already has a meaning, which is to treat `symm_color` as an array. It would be very confusing to repurpose it. Anyway, it doesn't exist.

Comment: yes, I expected something like that. Just a cozy flavor of multiple arrays as flexible members.

Comment: This is not specific to flexible array members. There's no shorthand for accessing members of struct arrays.

Comment: You can pass around and use the inner array directly, and retrieve the containing structure by deducting its field offset from the pointer cast to `(char*)`. That's a very efficient trick used a lot in malloc implementations and any other situation where you have to _hide_ metadata behind a pointer.

Comment: And btw, do NOT prefix the fields with the type of the containing structure (eg. `int symm_foo;`); K&R pre-ANSI C compilers (which used a single namespace for all field structures) went the way of the dodo a long, long, long time ago. And they never supported "flexible" arrays, anyways ;-)

Comment: @mosvy you mean something like
 struct s_symm_root{
       unsigned int size_c;
       char _[];
       } *symm_root;
?
 IDK, as for me, prefixes improve readability of a code. IDE anyway save your time on typing with suggestions.